# Can't send POST variables through telnet?

Tags: php, telnet

I know it is very simple, but I can't figure it out, if I make a request with telnet like this:

```
machine:~ user$ telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 7

vari=e3
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 10 Jul 2014 18:06:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/5.5.10 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.10
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: text/html

VARI =
```

The vari variable isn't set... the response should have VARI = e3 cause I have a PHP line that outputs it:

```
echo "VARI = ".$_POST['vari'];
exit;
```

But the variable doesn't appear. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `Content-type` header:

```
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! But why I obtain a 400 Bad Request if I omit the Host: in the Headers?

Comment: If you leave out `Host:` it doesn't know which virtual host you want.